# How to add more route points to the Google Directions route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Directions API. User put marker on the map for start and end point. Can you tell me how to add more route points to the route? For now I have only 2 markers I can add: start and end point. I wonder how should I define if I want to add 4,5, or more route points?
This is my code:

```
function addRoute(event) {
        if(markers.length < 50){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: event.latLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        if(markers.length == 2){
            var start = markers[0].getPosition();
            var end = markers[1].getPosition();

            putDirections(start, end);

            $(markers).each(function(i, marker){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
                    clearDirections();
                    var start = markers[0].getPosition();
                    var end = markers[1].getPosition();
                    putDirections(start, end);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to add [waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) to a DirectionsRequest?

Comment: User clicks on the map, and marker like start point shows up, user clicks again, B markers shows up, user clicks again and C marker shows up. so route is calculated from A to B, and from B to C automatically. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
directionsService.route({waypoints: waypts, /*other options*/});
```

You can also add optimizeWaypoints: true if you want google to calculate the order of waypoints to make the route shortest.